# GPUImageMovieWriter without the camera

Tags: gpuimage

I'm new to GPUImage, but I think that it is really nice: good work Brad.  I love the way the filters chain together so cleanly.

**GOAL**
I'm trying to wire up the following:
* create an openGL scene
* apply some filters (irrelevant to the discussion below)
* record to video

**PROBLEM**
My problem is I'm not clear how to connect up the recording.  Unfortunately, [interacting with opengl-es](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage#interacting-with-opengl-es) does not give me enough detail to work out what to do.

**ATTEMPT**
I have two starting points from the examples in the package:
* **CubeExample** - getting raw openGL to interact with GPUImage
* **SimpleVideoFileFilter** - recoding a video file through filters to a new file

I started with the CubeExample, substituted the videoCamera filter for GPUImageSolidColorGenerator (as an aside, I'm not sure how to start with no filter).  This allowed me to be able to create a mesh, render it and interact with it.  Then I thought that I'd simply add on a GPUImageMovieWriter filter as per the instructions given in [filtering and re-encoding a movie](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage#filtering-and-re-encoding-a-movie), but that requires coordination between the GPUImageMovie (the source) and the writer.  As I'm not wanting a camera stream or a video file as the source, but an animated openGL sequence, I'm not clear how to do it.  I've tried adding a `videoInputReadCallback` to the movieWriter:

```
movieWriter.videoInputReadyCallback = ^{
    [renderer nextFrame];
    [movieWriter newFrameReadyAtTime:renderer.cmTime atIndex:0];
};
```

where `nextFrame` is creates the next frame, calls `endProcessing` when done and sets the CMTime.  Without the `newFrameReadyAtTime:atIndex:` call, it works fine (animated image rendered as expected to the screen) except that it creates a video with only one frame in it.  With the `newFrameReadyAtTime:atIndex:` call, I get the message

```
Problem appending pixel buffer at time: 6
```

before it dies, which makes me think that the movieWriter is not yet ready for the renderer to present its frame, but I'm not sure what to do about it.  I've tried many other things, but to no avail.  From the description in Interacting with OpenGL-ES (see link above), it seems like it should be easy, but I'm not having any luck.

**REQUEST**
To make the question more relevant to others, I would just like it if someone might be able to post an example of creating an openGL scene (eg a triangle) and connecting it to GPUImageMovieWriter to record to a file, perhaps rotating the triangle for 10 frames so that we can see that more than a still image is created.

thanks.